# if checkbox var is greater/equal/lower than number, then

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple game with checkboxes, and I put some JavaScript to tell the user if they are winning or losing points. For this I've made this Script but is no working, can somebody please help me with this?

Although it changes it's value sucessfully, it only shows one message.

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var theTotal = 0;

 $("#one").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);    
  } else {
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);
  }
 });
  
  $("#two").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);    
  } else {
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);
  }
 });
  
  $("#three").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);    
  } else {
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);
  }
 });


  if (theTotal >= 4) {
      $("#ok").show();
    } else {
      $("#ok").hide();
    }

  if (theTotal >= 7) {
      $("#win").show();
    } else {
      $("#win").hide();
    }

  if (theTotal <= 3) {
      $("#lose").show();
    } else {
      $("#lose").hide();
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" type="checkbox" value="3">
<input id="two" type="checkbox" value="5">
<input id="three" type="checkbox" value="2">

<div id="win">You are winning!</div>
<div id="lose">You are losing!</div>
<div id="ok">You can do it better!</div>
<div class="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be EXACTLY how you wish it to work, but you just need to fix your `if` statements. The `if` statements need to run whenever an action occurs, which is the reason they only run once. They aren't called any other time.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var theTotal = 0;

 $("#one").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);    
  } else {
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);
  }
 });
  
  $("#two").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);    
  } else {
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);
  }
 });
  
  $("#three").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);    
  } else {
      theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
      $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);
  }
 });

$(".checkbox").on('click', function(){
 if (theTotal >= 4) {
      $("#ok").show();
    } else {
      $("#ok").hide();
    }

  if (theTotal >= 7) {
      $("#win").show();
    } else {
      $("#win").hide();
    }

  if (theTotal <= 3) {
      $("#lose").show();
    } else {
      $("#lose").hide();
    }
    
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" type="checkbox" value="3" class="checkbox">
<input id="two" type="checkbox" value="5" class="checkbox">
<input id="three" type="checkbox" value="2" class="checkbox">

<div id="win">You are winning!</div>
<div id="lose">You are losing!</div>
<div id="ok">You can do it better!</div>
<div class="total"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! works great and has the effect I wanted to, thanks again! =D

Comment: @Ermac no problem

Answer (score 1):

I normally don't do quite this much edit work on someone's code, but the degree to which you were breaking [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) was breaking my heart :)

First of all-- the reason your code was failing because you were only running your condition checks on the messaging a single time at the `document.ready` -- after that, your click handlers would run on each click, but the points evaluation never occurred again.

Secondly-- all your click handlers were identical.  As such, I made them into a single function, called anytime a checkbox was clicked.  And then I moved the points evaluation into that function.

Check it out below.  It's probably not 100% there, but hopefully it is enough to get you further down the path you want to be on.  Good luck-- happy coding!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var theTotal = 0;

    function evaluateChecked () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
            $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
        } else {
            theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
            $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
        }

        if (theTotal >= 4) {
            $("#ok").show();
        } else {
            $("#ok").hide();
        }

        if (theTotal >= 7) {
            $("#win").show();
        } else {
            $("#win").hide();
        }

        if (theTotal <= 3) {
            $("#lose").show();
        } else {
            $("#lose").hide();
        }

    }

    $('[type="checkbox"]').click(evaluateChecked);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" type="checkbox" value="3">
<input id="two" type="checkbox" value="5">
<input id="three" type="checkbox" value="2">

<div id="win">You are winning!</div>
<div id="lose">You are losing!</div>
<div id="ok">You can do it better!</div>
<div class="total"></div>
```

Comment: You definitely put more work into it than I did! :D I just added classes and used jQuery to run the functions whenever that class was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

When you write code inside `$(document).ready` function, it will execute only once. So, you need to call the update function on click event of the checkbox. Check below updated code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var theTotal = 0;

$("#one").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
        $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
    } else {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
        $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
    }
    updateValue();
});

$("#two").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
        $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
    } else {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
        $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
    }
    updateValue();
});

$("#three").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
        $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
    } else {
        theTotal = Number(theTotal) - Number($(this).val());
        $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
    }
    updateValue();
});

updateValue();

function updateValue() {
    if (theTotal >= 4) {
        $("#ok").show();
    } else {
        $("#ok").hide();
    }

    if (theTotal >= 7) {
        $("#win").show();
    } else {
        $("#win").hide();
    }

    if (theTotal <= 3) {
        $("#lose").show();
    } else {
        $("#lose").hide();
    }
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="one" type="checkbox" value="3">
<input id="two" type="checkbox" value="5">
<input id="three" type="checkbox" value="2">

<div id="win">You are winning!</div>
<div id="lose">You are losing!</div>
<div id="ok">You can do it better!</div>
<div class="total"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! it looks well! =D